# How to escape special characters in swagger schema example values?

Tags: jackson, yaml, swagger, openapi

In swagger (3.0) definition YAML, if I have a schema with a string property
and add a custom example value, special characters like `<`, `>`, and `&` appear "wrong" when browsed, e.g. `<` becomes `&lt;`.

I tried to use `\x3c` instead of `<`, or use `!!str` prefix, but doesn't help.

In this case the response is "application/xml", so that is may be a problem, however in the name of a property the less-then sign appears perfectly (see below).

Some special characters works fine, like `&`.

```
info:
  title: poc
servers:
- url: /poc/api
  variables: {}
paths:
  /ex2:
    get:
      tags:
      - example
      summary: debugging schema with example value contains < or >
      description:
      operationId: example
      responses:
        200:
          description: 
          content:
            application/xml;charset=UTF-8:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Wrapper'
components:
  schemas:
    Entry:
      type: object   
      properties:
        name:
           type: string
        value:
           type: number
    Wrapper:
      type: object   
      properties:
        entry:
           type: object
           $ref: '#/components/schemas/Entry'
        customfield:
           type: string
           example: "<hello\x3c"
        custom<>field:
           type: string
           example: "why"
```